# Where is `.objects` attribute is added to an instance namespace in django's models.Model class?

Tags: django, django-models

When in views.py we code something like `any_model_name.objects.all()` this thing brings us all the objects ever initiated from `any_model_name` class-model. I've just read all code in `models.Model` class (the one any model should inherit from) and I just can't find the place where `.objects` attribute appears there is nothing like that as well as `.all()` method attribute. My pycharm has the same opinion, it underlines `.objects` in red and says "Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'any_model_name'". What the magic prevents me from finding the place in django code where `.objects` thing appears for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is added by the *metaclass*, but in a bit of a cryptical way. Indeed, in the `_preprare` class of the `ModelBase` which is not the superclass of a `Model`, but its *typeclass*, [contributes this to the class <sup>[src]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/255f5345904854128647705adcb8d21138e87c63/django/db/models/base.py#L419):

> ```
>     def _prepare(cls):
>         # …
>         if not opts.managers:
>             # …
>             cls.add_to_class("objects", manager)
>         # …
> ```

The `.add_to_class` method will call the `.add_to_class` on the manager, that will then set itself as attribute on the class object.

The claim that every model has however an `.objects` is not true. This is only the case if you do not specify a manager yourself. Indeed, if you define a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    mymanager = models.Manager()
```

Then `MyManager` will *not* contain an `.objects`.

As for the `.all()` method itself, it works with the `_get_queryset_methods`. These return a dictionary with the name of the methods and its method. This will thus return a dictionary that maps `'all'` to a method that returns `self.get_queryset().all()`, since `get_queryset` will return a `QuerySet`, [it will thus call `.all()` on that queryset <sup>[src]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/255f5345904854128647705adcb8d21138e87c63/django/db/models/manager.py#L82-L105):

> ```
> @classmethod
> def _get_queryset_methods(cls, queryset_class):
>     def create_method(name, method):
>         @wraps(method)
>         def manager_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
>             return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>
>         return manager_method
>
>     new_methods = {}
>     for name, method in inspect.getmembers(
>         queryset_class, predicate=inspect.isfunction
>     ):
>         # Only copy missing methods.
>         if hasattr(cls, name):
>             continue
>         # Only copy public methods or methods with the attribute
>         # queryset_only=False.
>         queryset_only = getattr(method, "queryset_only", None)
>         if queryset_only or (queryset_only is None and name.startswith("_")):
>             continue
>         # Copy the method onto the manager.
>         new_methods[name] = create_method(name, method)
>     return new_methods
> ```

Most IDE's, code analysis tools, etc. will indeed not be capable to derive that a model has an `.objects` attribute, because it originates out of some sophisticated code in the typeclass.

PyCharm professional however has a Django plugin that can "understand" Django better, because the developers have hardcoded such logic. It thus contains some logic that does not analyze the typeclass code, but simply knows, because the developers of the module say that, added the manager.

Python is very flexible, dynamically-typed language, which often is a good idea. But code analysis sometimes can not follow the complexity of metaclasses, etc. and thus eventually fail to see how items are added to a class, which is a downside, compared to statically typed languages, for example.